# Rspec controller tests broken after switch to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I've originally been using SQLite with rspec without issue. However, since my production environment uses postgresql, I have changed rspec to use postgresql.

I am now getting errors that look like:

```
undefined method `models' for nil:NilClass
```

From what I can tell, model tests are still working fine whereas my controller tests throw the error I have posted above. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution had to do with my database not properly cleaning itself, I ended up using the "Database_Cleaner" gem: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner